# Which languages have the best support for stackful coroutines?

Tags: javascript, python, concurrency, iterator

Various languages support (some flavor of) coroutines.

One way to discriminate coroutines is whether they are *stackful* or not (terminology based on Ana Lucia de Moura; Roberto Ierusalimschy (2004). "Revisiting Coroutines". doi:10.1145/1462166.1462167. CiteSeerX: 10.1.1.58.4017.):

- *stackful* coroutines allow that a `yield` or `suspend` of a coroutine can be done from a function that is being called by a coroutine, i.e., from nested invocations and this implies that the whole call stack has to be preserved when the coroutine is suspended.
- non stackful coroutines impose the restriction that the `yield` or `suspend` can only be done in the body of the coroutine itself.

Clearly, stackful coroutines have advantages in terms of modularization but are more expensive to implement. My question is therefore: which languages have the best support for stackful coroutines?

Although I have looked at various languages (including Python, Ruby, Javascript, Lua, Scheme) the terminology in all these languages is so different and the descriptions are often so unclear that I prefer expert advice.

P.S. I am aware of the fact that coroutines can be implemented using continuations, but the question is specifically about languages that natively support coroutines.

Comment: asking for lists is not encouraged, because each answer is equally valid

Comment: @ratchetfreak: point taken, I have rephrased the question

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160145/which-languages-support-stackful-coroutines

Comment: @ratchetfreak while I agree with this rule, how could someone solve this question? Paul Klint: could you include a list of the languages you have looked at?

Comment: @gnat: I have deleted the question on stackoverflow

Comment: @DavyLandman: I have included a list of languages

Comment: I am not an expert, but I do not think that stackfull coroutines should be much more expensive than normal procedure calls.

Comment: @Giorgio: i disagree, the complete call stack has to be retained.

Comment: @PaulKlint: Don't you have to do the same for procedures? As long as a procedure does not exit, you retain the complete stack.

Comment: @Giorgio: the essential difference is that when an ordinary procedure returns its stack frame can be released. Since a coroutine can be resumed later on its frame has to be retained. The net effect is that a tree-structured stack is needed which branches for every suspended coroutine.

Comment: @Giorgio it is a bit like the overhead from recursive procedures, only more complex since a coroutine may have multiple exit and re-entry points.

Comment: OK, as I said, I am not an expert. I thought switching from one coroutine to another was not considered "returning" from the coroutine, but just suspending it.

Comment: Suspending means pushing state onto the stack.  One coroutine may call another, which might call a new instance of the first rather than yielding (or call a new instance and then, later in its code path, yield).  So there can be many instances of any coroutine open, all but the currently executed one with their state on the stack.

Comment: a very useful question closed off by SO morons that blindly follow rules. duh. typical of this community